# jta=true or xa-datasource in Jboss EAP 7

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jta

I'm trying to configure SQLSERVER datasource in standalone.xml. In my project i'm using JTA and i founded configuration with  and others with . What is the difference ? I'm using this:

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/mydatabase" pool-name="seguDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.40.16/mydatabase;instance=clust02</connection-url>
                    <driver>jtds-1.3.1.jar</driver>
                    <new-connection-sql>select 1</new-connection-sql>
                    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>50</max-pool-size>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
                    </validation>
                    <timeout>
                        <set-tx-query-timeout>true</set-tx-query-timeout>
                        <blocking-timeout-millis>5000</blocking-timeout-millis>
                        <idle-timeout-minutes>15</idle-timeout-minutes>
                    </timeout>
                    <statement>
                        <track-statements>false</track-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
```

This works for me but i'm afraid if it correct or i should change to XA-DATASOURCE.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a local-tx datasource in JBoss EAP 6.x or JBoss EAP 7, it defaults "jta" attribute to "true". This would help the local-tx resource to enlist in a global transaction. The "jta" attribute enables JTA integration for non-xa datasources only (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.1/html-single/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/index.html#Datasource_Parameters1).
If your application uses global transactions, i.e. it needs a transaction manager to coordinate a distributed transaction across multiple resource managers, then you need XA Datasource.

Comment: If i use non-xa datasources, without JTA, why i will need jta=true ? i can't understand the needed.

Comment: By default jta value is true in non-xa datasource if you didn't explicitly configured. jta="true" indicates that the datasource will honor the Java Transaction API and allows better tracking of connections by the JCA implementation.